# jenkins with github webhook don't work as expected

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, git-webhooks

I create 3 pipelines on jenkins with github webhook. These pipeline triggers  are *GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling* and all of these trigger have some repository and branch.

When I push code to the repository, I hope the 3 pipeline should all be trigger once. However, the 3 pipelines are triggered strangely. Two of 3 pipeline may  trigger twice, one of the 3 pipeline may be triggered once or zero times. But if there is only one pipeline, it works well. I don't know what should I do. I need your help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Check Jenkins logs.
https://jenkinsurl:port/log/all

Comment: I think I find what's going wrong. Now,I am working for a company which base on jenksin. We make a product based on Jenkins. Our customer can create code trigger jenksin pipeline on our product, while we will create a webhook on the code respository. If the customer make more than 3 same pipelines, we will make more than three different pipeline on the same  code respository(these webhook work same). I think this is why the strange thing happen.